# Query for eliminate duplicate records according to some codition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table from which i need to eliminate elements that have same code and different status.

For example this is my table:

```
+-------------+------------+
| Code        | Status     | 
+-------------+------------+
| 01          | 1          |                  
+-------------+------------+
| 02          | 1          |               
+-------------+------------+
| 03          | 1          |              
+-------------+------------+
| 01          | 2          |               
+-------------+------------+
```

The output should be like this one:

```
+-------------+------------+
| Code        | Status     |  
+-------------+------------+
| 02          | 1          |               
+-------------+------------+
| 03          | 1          |              
+-------------+------------+
```

It means that i need to eliminate Codes which have Status 1 and 2. In first table you can see that Code 01 have two has two statuses, status 1 and status 2 and in second table is not visible any more.

How to do that with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.code = t.code and t2.status <> t.status);
```

If there are duplicates in the original table, this will return the duplicates.  Alternatively, if you just want the codes that have a single status, with one row per code, you can use `group by`:

```
select t.code, max(t.status) as status
from t
group by t.code
having min(t.status) = max(t.status);
```